# how to implement Lazy loading to the angular material mat-expansion-panel ? while loading number of expantion panal in mat-accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading, accordion, angular-material-7

I need to implement the  Lazy rendering to the `mat-expansion-panel`, not to the `matExpansionPanelContent`
I have thousands of record and I am displaying it in the `mat-expansion-panel`, I need to load the `mat-expansion-panel` by using Lazy rendering first I need to load some set of records like 15 when I scroll down it should render next set of records.

the problem is it's taking more than 1 min to load 1000's od records

i have a ngfor which can have more then 1000's of records like.

```
<mat-accordion>
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="something">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    This is the expansion title
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
    Some deferred content
  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

the actual result should load a set of `mat-expansion-panel` and when scrolling it should render the next set of `mat-expansion-panel`

Comment: Use the Virtual Scroll feature from the CDK: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview